# Making use of fullscreen on the extended display

Tags: display, displayport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run an app in Full Screen mode on OS X Lion on my second monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/how-do-i-run-an-app-in-full-screen-mode-on-os-x-lion-on-my-second-monitor)

I recently bought a MiniDisplay Port to VGA to make use of my unused monitor.  So far I'm using it but one thing I notice is that when I try to use the fullscreen option of a certain application, Safari for example, OS X Lion only seem to use the main display (my MBP's monitor).

When I drag Safari's window on the extended display and then fullscreen from there, the fullscreen window still returns back to the main display.

Is there a way for putting the fullscreen window to the extend display?

Cheers!

Comment: I see.  This thread must be closed then.  I'm not doing my homework well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Feel free to remove your question if you agree it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Mountain Lion by dragging the window to the secondary screen before entering fullscreen, but unfortunately cannot be done in Mac OS X Lion.